# CUDA: unspecified launch failure on cudaGraphicsUnmapResources

Tags: opengl, cuda

Currently, I'm using CUDA and OpenGL to simulating ocean.

I found that when the number of vertices is around `6,000` or `25,000`, the program works correctly. But if the number of vertices is around `100,000`  or `400,000`, I get `unspecified launch failure` error.

This is the code I use to update vertices positions and normals with CUDA in a frame:

```
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    ...

    vec3 *d_vertices = NULL, *d_normals = NULL;
    cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &cudaVboResVertices, 0);
    cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &cudaVboResNormals, 0);

    cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer(
        (void**)&d_vertices, NULL, cudaVboResVertices
    );
    cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer(
        (void**)&d_normals, NULL, cudaVboResNormals
    );

    //update vertices positions and normals
    //faceNumber*3 is the number of vertices
    launchGPUKernel(faceNumber*3, d_vertices, d_normals);
    t += dt;

    //the error first occurs at this line at the first iteration
    cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, &cudaVboResNormals, 0);

    cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, &cudaVboResVertices, 0);

    ...
}
```

The `launchGPUKernel` is like this:

```
void launchGPUKernel(int num_points, vec3 *d_vtxs, vec3 *d_nmls){
    dim3 grid(num_points/512 + 1, 1);
    dim3 block(16, 64, 1);
    d_update<<<grid, block>>>(num_points, WAVE_NUM, d_vtxs, d_nmls, d_wave_paras, t);
}
```

The `d_update`:

```
__global__ void d_update(
    int num_points, int wave_num,
    vec3 *d_vtxs, vec3 *d_nmls, float *d_wv_prs,
    float d_time
){
    long block_number = blockIdx.x + blockIdx.y*gridDim.x;
    block_number *= (blockDim.x*blockDim.y);//the number of threads before current block
    long idx = threadIdx.x + threadIdx.y*blockDim.x;
    idx += block_number;

    float x, z, height;
    x = d_vtxs[idx].x;
    z = d_vtxs[idx].z;
    height = 0;

    for (size_t j = 0; j < wave_num; j++) {
        float a, b, theta, omega, phi;
        a = d_wv_prs[j*5+0];
        b = d_wv_prs[j*5+1];
        theta = d_wv_prs[j*5+2];
        omega = d_wv_prs[j*5+3];
        phi = d_wv_prs[j*5+4];

        float temp = (cos(theta)*x + sin(theta)*z)*omega + d_time*phi;
        height += a*cos(temp) + b*sin(temp);
    }

    d_vtxs[idx].y = height;


    float Hx, Hz;
    Hx = 0;
    Hz = 0;

    for (size_t j = 0; j < wave_num; j++) {
        float a, b, theta, omega, phi;
        a = d_wv_prs[j*5+0];
        b = d_wv_prs[j*5+1];
        theta = d_wv_prs[j*5+2];
        omega = d_wv_prs[j*5+3];
        phi = d_wv_prs[j*5+4];

        float temp = (cos(theta)*x + sin(theta)*z)*omega + d_time*phi;
        Hx += -sin(temp)*omega*cos(theta)*a + cos(temp)*omega*cos(theta)*b;
        Hz += -sin(temp)*omega*sin(theta)*a + cos(temp)*omega*sin(theta)*b;
    }

    vec3 v3_temp = normalize( vec3(-Hx, 1, -Hz) );
    d_nmls[idx].x = v3_temp.x;
    d_nmls[idx].y = v3_temp.y;
    d_nmls[idx].z = v3_temp.z;
}
```

I don't know what is wrong.

## Environment

OS X EI Captitan 10.11.6

CUDA 8.0

OpenGL 4.0

Comment: Reading [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__INTEROP.html#group__CUDART__INTEROP_1g11988ab4431b11ddb7cbde7aedb60491) "Note that this function may also return error codes from previous, asynchronous launches.". The problem is with a prior kernel and I would *guess* it is because you are hitting the display driver watchdog timer limit. This problem is very well documented, if you care to search around a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured it out.

The problem is that the number of threads I set is more than the number of vertices I have due to the code in `launchGPUKernel`:

```
dim3 grid(num_points/512 + 1, 1);
dim3 block(16, 64, 1);
```

This caused `d_vtxs[idx]` and `d_nmls[idx]` accessed addresses that do not exist.

When I changed it to

```
dim3 grid(num_points/(16*64), 1);
dim3 block(16, 64, 1);
```

it works correctly.